# Redirect feed URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

https://www.example.com/download/page-name/feed

I want redirect only https://www.example.com/download/page-name/feed to https://www.example.com/download/page-name/

But not redirect (As if it doesn't affect) https://www.example.com/page-name/feed

Only replace feed from https://www.example.com/download/page-name/feed

Using htaccess

How can I do. Many thanks for the help.

How can I do. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you implement a redirection rule that matches the path of the incoming request (so `/download/page-name/feed`) and redirect it to the desired target. You will find endless examples for such rules here on SO. Also there are many tutorials offering help with how to get started implementing such a rule.